# Which ReportViewer version in ASP.NET 2.0 VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, version, report-viewer2010

I am building a WebApp (ASP.NET 2.0 C#) on VS2010.

App is working fine and I thought I put a Report functionality so I installed ReportViewer 2010.

When I dragged ReportViewer control from the Tookbox and ran the page, I got some sort of assembly reference error so I added Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForm in Reference. However there was only 8.0.0.0 version.

When I try running, it gave me:

```
The base class includes the field 'ReportViewer1', but its type (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer).
```

I assume this is happening because I did not reference Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm 10.0.0.0.
Anyone know why I do not have that in my reference list and how do I get it on there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 normally works with Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm 10.0.0.0. I wonder why you ended up with the super old version 8.0.0.0. However, you can add [manually Add or Remove References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and/or manually replace the `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm 8.0.0.0` with `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm 10.0.0.0` in your web.config.

If for some reason you don't have installed it on your machine you can install [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442).

Although I'm using ASP.Net 2.0 with `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm 10.0.0.0` as well and so far I had no problems. The compiler warns about Framework 4.0 being referenced by `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm` and suggests upgrading to ASP.Net 4.0